# MarkerCluster don't work with geojson layer in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, ajax

I have created gejson layers and I want to use MarkerCluster option in one of them. But I don't know what am I doing wrong and where in my code is a problem. 
I tried something like this:

Scripts:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
```

And code with the layer which should MarkerClustered:

```js
var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

$.getJSON("data/Fotografie.geoJSON", function(geojson) {
  var Fotografie = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
      return new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: new myIcon({
          iconUrl: 'icons/accessdenied.png',
          iconSize: [32, 37],
          iconAnchor: [16, 37],
          popupAnchor: [0, -37]
        })
      })
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name, {
          maxWidth: "auto"
        }) //popup dostosowany do wielkosci zdjecia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170366/leaflet-adjust-popup-to-picture-size
    }

  });
  var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
  clusters.addLayer(Fotografie);
  map.addLayer(clusters);

  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Fotografie');
});
```

When I put my code like this the "Fotografie" layer don't even show up. Help.

---

It's the whole code. I don't know which version of MasterCluster I have.

```
    
        div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:800px">

        link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
        link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.css"/>
        link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.css" />
        link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js">
        script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
        script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"> 

        script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.js">
        script type="text/javascript">


            var map = L.map('map');

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

            map.attributionControl.addAttribution("Dane: OpenStreetMap");

            var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

$.getJSON("data/Zabudowa.geoJSON", function (geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
        'weight': 0,
        'fillColor': 'brown',
        'fillOpacity': 1
      }
    },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){  
            var popupText = "Numer obiektu: " + feature.properties.OBJECTID
                + "
Sposob uzytkowania: " + feature.properties.type 
                + "
More info";
            layer.bindPopup(popupText); 
      }
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Zabudowa');
});

$.getJSON("data/Drogi.geoJSON", function (geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
        'weight': 1,
        'color': 'red',
        'fillOpacity': 0
      }
    },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
        layer.bindPopup ("Nazwa ulicy: " + feature.properties.name + "
Dopuszczalna predkosc: " + feature.properties.maxspeed + "
Numer drogi: " + feature.properties.ref)
        }
  });
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Drogi');
});

    var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        iconUrl: 'icons/cemetery-24.png'

    });

$.getJSON("data/miejsca_pamieci.geoJSON", function (geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
   pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
          return new L.Marker(latLng, {
            icon: new myIcon({
              iconUrl: 'icons/cemetery-24.png',
              iconSize: [24, 24],
              iconAnchor: [12, 24],
              popupAnchor: [0, -24]
            })
          })
      },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
        layer.bindPopup ("Opis: " + feature.properties.Opis)
        }
  });
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Miejsca_pamieci');
});

    var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        iconUrl: 'icons/accessdenied.png'

    });

$.getJSON("data/Fotografie.geoJSON", function (geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
          return new L.Marker(latLng, {
            icon: new myIcon({
              iconUrl: 'icons/accessdenied.png',
              iconSize: [32, 37],
              iconAnchor: [16, 37],
              popupAnchor: [0, -37]
            })
          })
      },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
        layer.bindPopup (feature.properties.Name, {  maxWidth: "auto"})//popup dostosowany do wielkosci zdjecia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170366/leaflet-adjust-popup-to-picture-size
      }
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Fotografie');
});


            map.setView([53.07908, 18.22422],12);


            L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

But I want to Cluster only Fotografie layer which is point layer with displayed photo when clicked.

Comment: There does not seem to be any particular issue in the code you posted. You should probably share more code (you do not show what is `myIcon` for instance), and specify which versions of Leaflet and Leaflet.markercluster you use. Ideally also reproduce your issue on Plunker, JSBin or JSFiddle. BTW, your last line with `geojsonLayer` seems unrelated.

Comment: BTW, does it work at least with an `L.layerGroup()` instead of `L.markerClusterGroup()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your above additional code, it looks like you are loading Leaflet.markercluster script *before* Leaflet script:

```html
<script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js">
```

You should rather load it **after**:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js">
<script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js">
```

You should learn to use your browser **console** (on Windows / Linux browsers, press <kbd>F12</kbd>; on Mac OS browsers, press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) to look for potential errors.

In your case, I suspect there should be something like "`ReferenceError: L is not defined`" due to Leaflet.markercluster trying to attach some code to Leaflet's `L` namespace, but could not find it because it is not loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for advices - I'm still green at it. I have replaced scripts as You told and I found out to remove .addTo(map) from code. That helps after all:)